# EnumWindows( ) doesn't find some top level windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, process

I am trying to create a program that functions similar to a task manager along with many other capabilities. Currently, I am having trouble finding all the top-level windows with my current enumeration function. For some reason, it enumerates and fills out the HWND for some applications properly ( e.g. Google Chrome, Command Prompt, Code::Blocks ), but not for some games( e.g. Roblox ( only one I tested ) ). I tried to see if maybe FindWindow() would fail too, but it worked fine in that context. Which means that EnumWindows() should obviously find it, but apparently I either did something wrong or I read something wrong in the documentation. I really don't want to have to use FindWindow( ) when I probably won't know the title of most windows anyways.

**Enumeration function :**

```
BOOL CALLBACK FindWindows( HWND handle, LPARAM option )
{
    DWORD window_process_id = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( handle, &window_process_id );
    process_list * p1 = NULL;

    switch ( option )
    {
        case FIND_WINDOW_HANDLE :
            if ( IsWindowEnabled( handle ) )
                for ( p1 = head_copy; p1; p1 = p1->next )
                    if ( p1->pid == window_process_id )
                        p1->window_handle = handle;
        break;

        default :
            SetLastError( ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER );
            return 0;
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Full source :**

```
/* Preprocessor directives */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define TARGET_PROCESS "chrome.exe"

/* Structures */

typedef struct process_list
{
    char * process_name;
    DWORD pid;
    HANDLE process_handle;
    HWND window_handle;

    int process_name_sz;

    struct process_list * next;
} process_list;

typedef struct drawing_data
{
    RECT window_pos;
} drawing_data;

/* Enums ( Global integer constants ) */

enum
{
    FIND_WINDOW_HANDLE
};

enum
{
    TIMER_START,
    TIMER_STOP,
    TIMER_GETDIFF
};

typedef struct t_timer
{
    clock_t start_time;
    clock_t end_time;
} t_timer;

/* Global variables */

process_list * head_copy = NULL;

/* ***************************************************************** */
/* Time functions */

clock_t timer( int command, t_timer * timer1 )
{
    switch ( command )
    {
        case TIMER_START :
            timer1->start_time = clock( );
        break;

        case TIMER_STOP :
            timer1->end_time = clock( );
        break;

        case TIMER_GETDIFF :
            return ( ( timer1->end_time - timer1->start_time ) / ( CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000 ));
        break;

        default : break;
    }

    return -1;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */
/* Windows error functions */

void show_error( char * user_string, BOOL exit )
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
    DWORD error_code = GetLastError( );

    FormatMessage
    (
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        error_code,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) buffer,
        BUFSIZ,
        NULL
    );

    printf( "%s : %s", user_string, buffer );

    if ( exit ) ExitProcess( error_code );

    return;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

void win_error( char * message, BOOL exit )
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
    DWORD error_code = GetLastError( );

    FormatMessage
    (
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        error_code,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) buffer,
        BUFSIZ,
        NULL
    );

    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Error from System :", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK );

    if ( exit ) ExitProcess( error_code );

    return;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */
/* Linked list functions */

process_list * create( )
{
    process_list * temp = NULL;

    if ( !( temp = malloc( sizeof( process_list ) ) ) )
    {
        perror("Malloc");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    return temp;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

process_list * add( process_list * head, HANDLE process_handle, PROCESSENTRY32 * process_structure )
{
    process_list * temp = NULL;

    if ( !head )
    {
        head = create( );

        head->pid = process_structure->th32ParentProcessID;
        head->process_handle = process_handle;
        head->process_name_sz = strlen( process_structure->szExeFile ) + 1;
        head->process_name = malloc( head->process_name_sz );

        if ( !head->process_name )
        {
            perror( "Malloc" );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        strcpy( head->process_name, process_structure->szExeFile );
        head->next = NULL;
    } else
    {
        temp = create( );
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;

        head->pid = process_structure->th32ParentProcessID;
        head->process_handle = process_handle;
        head->process_name_sz = strlen( process_structure->szExeFile ) + 1;
        head->process_name = malloc( head->process_name_sz );

        if ( !head->process_name )
        {
            perror( "Malloc" );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        strcpy( head->process_name, process_structure->szExeFile );
    }

    return head;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

void print_list( process_list * head )
{
    process_list * p1 = NULL;

    for ( p1 = head; p1; p1 = p1->next  )
    {
        printf(
               "-------------------------------------------------\n"
               "node.process_name\t=\t%s\n"
               "node.process_id\t\t=\t%d\n"
               "\nCan terminate process : %s\n\n"
               "node.window_handle\t=\t0x%p\n"
               "node.next\t\t=\t%s\n",
               p1->process_name,
               ( int )p1->pid,
               p1->process_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? "NO" : "YES",
               ( void * )p1->window_handle,
               p1->next ? "(node address)\n" : "NULL"
              );
    }
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

void print_node( process_list * node )
{
    printf(
            "node.process_name\t=\t%s\n"
            "node.process_id\t\t=\t%d\n"
            "\nCan terminate process : %s\n\n"
            "node.window_handle\t=\t0x%p\n"
            "node.next\t\t=\t%s\n",
            node->process_name,
            ( int )node->pid,
            node->process_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? "NO" : "YES",
            ( void * )node->window_handle,
            node->next ? "(node address)\n" : "NULL"
           );

    return;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

process_list * delete( process_list * head, process_list * node )
{
    process_list * p1 = head;
    process_list * p2 = NULL;

    if ( !p1 )
        return NULL;
    else if ( p1 == node )
    {
        if ( !p1->next )
        {
            free( p1->process_name );
            if ( p1->process_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
                CloseHandle( p1->process_handle );
            if ( p1->window_handle )
                CloseHandle( p1->window_handle );

            free( p1 );
        }
        else
        {
            free( p1->process_name );
            if ( p1->process_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
                CloseHandle( p1->process_handle );
            if ( p1->window_handle )
                CloseHandle( p1->window_handle );

            p2 = head->next;
            free( p1 );

            return p2;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    for ( ; p1 && p1 != node; p2 = p1, p1 = p1->next );

    if ( !p1 )
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        free( p1->process_name );
        if ( p1->process_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
            CloseHandle( p1->process_handle );
        if ( p1->window_handle )
            CloseHandle( p1->window_handle );

        p2->next = p1->next;
        free( p1 );
    }

    return head;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

void free_list( process_list * head )
{
    process_list * p1 = head;
    process_list * p2 = NULL;

    while ( p1 )
    {
        free(  p1->process_name );
        if ( p1->process_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
            CloseHandle( p1->process_handle );
        if ( p1->window_handle )
            CloseHandle( p1->window_handle );

        p2 = p1;
        p1 = p1->next;

        free( p2 );
    }

    return;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

process_list * find_process_and_copy_node( process_list * head, const char * process_name )
{
    BOOL is_match = FALSE;
    process_list * p1 = NULL;
    process_list * new_node = NULL;

    for ( p1 = head; p1; p1 = p1->next )
    {
        if ( !strcmp( p1->process_name, process_name ) )
        {
            is_match = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( is_match )
    {
        new_node = create( );
        new_node->pid = p1->pid;
        new_node->process_handle = p1->process_handle;

        if ( !( new_node->process_name = malloc( p1->process_name_sz ) ) )
        {
            perror( "Malloc" );
            free( new_node );
            free_list( head );
            exit( 1 );
        }

        new_node->process_name = strcpy( new_node->process_name, p1->process_name );
        new_node->process_name_sz = p1->process_name_sz;
        new_node->window_handle = p1->window_handle;

        new_node->next = NULL;

        return new_node;
    }
    else return NULL;

}

/* ***************************************************************** */
/* WinAPI functions */

BOOL CALLBACK FindWindows( HWND handle, LPARAM option )
{
    DWORD window_process_id = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( handle, &window_process_id );
    process_list * p1 = NULL;

    switch ( option )
    {
        case FIND_WINDOW_HANDLE :
            if ( IsWindowEnabled( handle ) )
                for ( p1 = head_copy; p1; p1 = p1->next )
                    if ( p1->pid == window_process_id )
                        p1->window_handle = handle;
        break;

        default :
            SetLastError( ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER );
            return 0;
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

process_list * get_process_list( process_list * head )
{
    HANDLE h_process_snap;
    HANDLE h_process;
    PROCESSENTRY32 process_structure;

    h_process_snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

    if( h_process_snap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        show_error( "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", FALSE );
        return NULL;
    }

    process_structure.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    if( !Process32First( h_process_snap, &process_structure ) )
    {
        show_error( "Process32First", FALSE );
        CloseHandle( h_process_snap );
        return NULL;
    }

    do
    {
        h_process = OpenProcess( PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, process_structure.th32ProcessID );

        if ( h_process )
            head = add( head, h_process, &process_structure );
        else
            head = add( head, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, &process_structure );
    } while( Process32Next( h_process_snap, &process_structure ) );

    CloseHandle( h_process_snap );
    return head;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

process_list * find_process( const char * process_name )
{
    process_list * head = NULL;
    process_list * target_process = NULL;

    if ( !( head = get_process_list( head ) ) )
        exit( 1 );

    head_copy = head;

    if ( !EnumWindows( FindWindows, FIND_WINDOW_HANDLE ) )
        win_error( "EnumWindows", FALSE );

    target_process = find_process_and_copy_node( head, TARGET_PROCESS );
    free_list( head );

    return target_process;
}

/* ***************************************************************** */

int main( )
{
    t_timer program_run_time;
    memset( &program_run_time, 0, sizeof( t_timer ) );
    timer( TIMER_START, &program_run_time );

    process_list * target_process = NULL;

    printf("Searching for target process...\n");

    while ( !( target_process = find_process( TARGET_PROCESS ) ) )
        Sleep( 100 );

    printf("Found!\n\n");
    print_node( target_process );

    timer( TIMER_STOP, &program_run_time );
    printf( "\n\n\t--\tProgram run time : %d milliseconds\t--\t\n\n", ( int )timer( TIMER_GETDIFF, &program_run_time ) );

    free( target_process->process_name );
    free( target_process );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be storing a wrong Id in `process_list::pid`. You likely want `PROCESSENTRY32::th32ProcessID`, not `th32ParentProcessID`

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant code. Please strip it down to a minimal [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the same problem. In addition to what Igor said, your callback is also not taking into account that a process can have multiple top-level windows. If your callback really is not finding the intended windows, then use Spy++ or similar tool to verify that the windows are actually top-level to begin with. Just because a window *looks* like it is a top-level window does not guarantee that it *really is* a top-level window.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem. Also, I really did try to point out the code that was problematic, but I'll be sure to actually shorten it into a smaller program next time.

Answer (score -3):

If you can see it in Spy++, you should be able to get at it with EnumWindows.

But if your query is ROBLOX-specific and all you want is the window handle, you can do

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.MainWindowTitle == "Roblox - [Place1]")
            {
                rbxProc = p;
                Console.WriteLine("FOUND ROBLOX Process");
            }
        }
```

and then you can get the main handle like this:

```
rbxProc.MainWindowHandle
```

Comment: Not to be offensive, but did you confuse C# with C/C++? This question is clearly written with high level code that is invalid to the question and inappropriate in this context. There is no good translation for the code you wrote really, with there being no MainWindowHandle in regular win32 code.

Comment: Because the winapi is the same in all languages and that is code that I had laying around?